# Changing picture on mousemove in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, mousemove

I came across [this](http://w00tmedia.net/) site, and wanted to implement something similar to their picture changing logo whilst the mouse is moving into my own site. I'm not sure if it uses jQuery as the page source is a little confusing, is there anyway for me to do this within javascript?

Comment: Use jQuery mouseover event to change the src of the image

Comment: Actual implementation on how to do this may be out of the scope for an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that site is using a background sprite, and display each logo changing the position of the sprite.

This is the sprite image for the logo:
http://w00tmedia.net/wp-content/themes/w00t/images/citrus-logos.png

You should do some math based on the sprites layout and how 'quickly' you want to change the image.

See this, 
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

And then change the element's  background position.

Comment: Sprites will do, no need for JS here.

Comment: Sprites also have the added benefit that all the images are 'pre-loaded' since there is only one big image, as opposed to having different images, wich will cause the newly loaded images to flicker for a while until they are fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish the same effect using css if you have a div or some other block element instead of an image tag.

```
#logo {
background: url('logo.png');
width: 200px;
height: 45px;
}

#logo:hover {
background: url('logo_hover.png');
}
```